# write to serial port while receiving tcp data

Tags: c, sockets, serial-port, posix

I am writing a program that is supposed to accept information from both a tcp/ip port and a serial port. It is also supposed to write to the serial port as well. I have two programs (one for serial and one for tcp/ip) but I am attempting to place them into one whole program. The result I am getting is that I will only read the serial data when tcp/ip data is read. This isn't such a problem. The big problem is that the write function doesn't seem to be working at all. Does anyone know why?

Here is the code to the method that performs the serial functions. the main method creates the tcp/ip socket and calls this method:

```
    int work()
    {

      //set up the serial port
       int result = 0;
       int portID = -1;
       char *device = "/dev/ttyUSB1";
       int rate = convertRate("115200");
       char parity = convertParity("N");
       int databits = convertDatabits("8");
       int stopbits = convertStopbits("1");
       portID = posixComOpen(device,rate,parity,databits,stopbits);


      maxslot = listener;
      do
      {

        fd_set set;
        int i;

        FD_ZERO(&set);

        FD_SET(1,        &set);
        FD_SET(listener, &set);
        for(i=0; i < SLOTCOUNT; i++)
        {
          if(slots[i])
          {
            FD_SET(slots[i], &set);
          }
        }

        int koliko = select(maxslot+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(koliko==-1)
          err(5, "select()");

        if(FD_ISSET(1, &set))
        {

          int size;
          if(ioctl(1, FIONREAD, &size) != -1){
            char *buf;

        //    printf("Reading %d bytes...\n", size);
            buf = malloc(size+1);
            read(1, buf, size);
            buf[size] = 0;
        //    printf("Received %s\n", buf);

            broadcast_message(0, buf);

            free(buf);
          }
          else
            err(7, "ioctl() stdio");

        }
        if(FD_ISSET(listener, &set))
        {
          int accepted = accept(listener, NULL, NULL);
          if(accepted == -1)
            err(6, "accept()");

          slots[accepted] = accepted;
          if(accepted > maxslot)
            maxslot = accepted;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < SLOTCOUNT; i++)
        {
          if(slots[i] && FD_ISSET(slots[i], &set))
          {
        //    printf("Received on %d\n", i);


            int size;


            if(ioctl(i, FIONREAD, &size) != -1){

              if(size > 0)
              {
                char *buf;

        //        printf("Reading %d bytes...\n", size);
                buf = malloc(size+1);
                read(i, buf, size);
                buf[size] = 0;
        //        printf("Received %s\n", buf);

                broadcast_message(i, buf);

                free(buf);
              }
              else
              {
                shutdown(i, SHUT_RDWR);
                close(i);

                slots[i] = 0;

        //        printf("Disconnect on %d\n", i);
              }
            }
            else
              err(8, "ioctl() net");


          }
        }
        //recieve and send data to serial
char input =0;

        while(posixComDataReady(portID) && posixComRead(portID, &input)) {
        printf("%c", input);
        //fflush(stdout);
          } //while

         /* Write character to Vex */
         if(posixComWrite(portID, 'x') < 0)
           printf("Error Writing char %c",'x');
         //end serial code

      } while(1);
      return 0;
    }
```

EDiT: here is the poxixComWrite() method:

```
char posixComWrite(int port, char src) {
return (write(port, &src, 1) == 1);
} //posixComWrite
```

Again, this program IS working except for the PosixComWrite() method. It does not throw an error.it returns "1". I have it writing to a micro-controller which doesn't receive the char. This WAS working when taken out of the context of the tcp/ip. Is there some weird happenings going on here?

Comment: What do you mean by `posixComWrite()` not working? It doesn't send anything? It fails with error? What's inside `posixComWrite()`?

Comment: It is just the write() method. I have edited my post.

Answer (score -2):

Try to suspend the process, which writes for a few milliseconds just before writing. It will the context switch and will eliminate some of the problems.

Comment: Do you mean use usleep() for a few milliseconds or use the suspend() function?

Comment: Don't go this way, even if it works it's a hack, not a solution.

Comment: I meant usleep. the process in any operating system moves through three states interrupt -> Ready-> Run. When you do IO (or networking in your case) you move the process into interrupt state. Depending on how your system is set up you may not be able to get into the runs state again to facilitate another interrupt for TCP/IP or Serial. The dummy interrupt may just allow the process to go through another context switch which does not involve any of the I/O operations. This is not by any chance a final solution. However, it will allow you to separate process control problems from I/O problems

Comment: I placed a usleep(500) before the method call and it didn't seem to effect the result at all.

Comment: Then it is not an interrupt problem. The only sign it shows that these two calls work separately but do not work in the same program. Try to move them into the different threads to trick the context switch again. You can also try (if you haven't yet) to trade the places of these two calls. It may not make a difference but it would give you an idea what may be wrong. These problems take long time to crack. Keep me posted because I am interested in what went wrong there. What is the platform? Is it possible to see the whole program?

Comment: I'll put them in separate threads and see how it goes. Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/ykDaezc3

Comment: On the first glance I see a couple of "trouble" spots. As far as I remember ports 0,1,2 are reserved by OS for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR. Maybe it has changed and just requires clarification because you look at port 1. Another one is maxslot+1. Are you sure that ports are sequentially assigned? I would put few print statements there to see that the ports are not getting mixed up. Also your portID is assigned by the system from the available port descriptors. check if it is not overlapped with slots from the array. Anyway, put more print statements where ports are assigned

Comment: Hmm, are you confusing ports with descriptors? Also, descriptors 0,1,2 are not reserved, they refer to STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR at startup, but nothing stops the application from closing and reusing them (yet it's a bad practice).